# Excel incorrectly calculating the average of numbers when using division

Tags: excel, average, division

I am trying to work out the average of scores for the male artists. When I tried using the AVERAGEIFs function it returned a #VALUE error and therefore I have created a table to work out the average manually. The expected score is 3.9 however when I use my table which adds up all the scores and then the number of scores which are not blank and divides the total score by number of scores the answer is 3.4.

Could you please advise on why this would be and if there is a way to calculate the average of male artists?

Here is an image of my spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: It is a lot easier for us if you post data rather than a screenshot. I'm not waiting for jobs like copying your data from a screenshot into a spreadsheet.

Comment: If you make a normal Average and you make it per column, thus it would be `AVG(Q1:Q5)`, and then make it `AVERAGEIFS()` with that column and the Artist and Male as conditions, would it be what you expect?

Comment: Really @jkpieterse..? Personally I live for the opportunity to waste my time retyping someone's crappy data just so I have a chance at helping them. It's esspecially exciting when I get to guess at the formula that 'didn't work' 'cause they didn't bother to include it.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be 3.857142857?

Comment: @Jeeped LOL. The things we do to try and help...

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, `AVERAGEIFS()` works on a single column / single row.
Thus, you need a helping row, showing you the AVERAGE per person, and then taking the average, with conditions such as Gender and Job.

[image]

I have 6.5 with this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(F2:F5 F2:F5,B2:B5,B2,A2:A5,A2)
```

It simply gives the average of 2 and 11, as they are the only 2 male artists in my sample.

[MSDN AVERAGEIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

If you do not like the idea of additional column, then making a PIVOT table would be a good solution.